# Reading a password from a file for authentication purpose Java

Tags: java, passwords

I am having trouble with matching the input entered for a user's password and the actual password of the user(if the user exists). The actual password is stored in a file as a character array. I tried printing the array as a string but the output was the same as the character array representation.

The following code snippet reads the password from the file and compares it to the one the user has entered in order to determine whether the users should be logged into the client. The file stores the data in the following way - "user" , "password" , "address".

Example date from a file:

radi1006, [C@4f1c987b, The Shire, SO1

```
    public void checkCredentials(String username, char[] password)
    {

        if(fileExists("users" + File.separator + username + ".txt"))
        {
            FileReader fileR;
            BufferedReader buffR = null;

            try
            {

                fileR = new FileReader("users" + File.separator + username + ".txt");
                buffR = new BufferedReader(fileR);

                String[] info = buffR.readLine().split(", ");    

                if(Arrays.equals(password,info[1].toCharArray()))
                {
                    loginResponse = "success";
                    client = new ClientApplication();
                    client.init();
                }
                else
                {
                    loginResponse = "Wrong username or password.";
                    return;
                }
            }    
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    buffR.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            loginResponse = "There is no such user.";
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of your `password` variable?

Comment: What's missing from your logic is any encryption of the password.  It's dangerous to store passwords as clear text in a file, and if you're doing that, then you might want to reconsider your approach.

Comment: @GregKopff I am passing the value from a JPasswordField that returns a character array.

Comment: @TimBiegeleise I know but this is just for a programming coursework.

Comment: Are the fields actually quote in your text file?  I suspect the root cause is that you're reading in the data incorrectly.

Comment: maybe there is a blank in your split that seems not to be in the file "user,"password","adresse" and you split on ", ".

Comment: @Nemesis I looked carefully at it several times. It is just that when i try to print the input password as a string i get the actual value but when i do it for the one stored on the file i get something similar to this [C@5bdb7b7.

Comment: The snippet posted above compare password to an array of char (ie it's memory adress) then you don't get the expected result. what's the passord's type (String i suppose)? or is it an array? then the below answer should give you the correct code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using ",(whitespace)" as a delimiter

Comment: Edit your question and show us the single line from a sample file.

Comment: How are you writing the password?  As text, or as some kind of encoded binary?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just write the char array that JPasswordField's getPassword() returns

Comment: If `[C@4f1c987b` is literally in the file, then it looks like you didn't write the password into the file properly.  `[C@4f1c987b` is what you get when you call `.toString()` on a `char[]` value.

Comment: @GregKopff Agreed.  He dumped an array to file, this is the likely explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Example date from a file:
>
> `radi1006, [C@4f1c987b, The Shire, SO1`

It looks like your problem is not reading in and comparing the values.  Rather, you've not stored the password in the file correctly.

`[C@4f1c987b` is what you get when you call `.toString()` on a `char[]`.

(If someone supplied `[C@4f1c987b` as the password, your code would pass it).

When you get a `char[]` from a password field and want to write it to a text file, then it needs to be turned into a String.  Essentially:

```
final String s = new String(password, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

(This assumes we're not overly concerned with security, as the reason a `JPasswordField` doesn't return a String is so that the String doesn't hang around on the heap in cleartext.  Read about that [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword--).)

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything.